# Removing Content and Selector in CSS from first item

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having selector with my CSS with the following code:-

```
   nav { font-size:13px; }

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:18px;
}
.nav ol, ul {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.nav a {
    min-height:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding: 20px 20px 10px 0;
}

.nav a:before {
    content: "| ";
    color: #00aeef;
    margin-right: 5px;
}



.nav a:hover {
    color:#00aeef;
}
```

What this does is that it puts "|" with all the menu items, but I don't want it to be with the first menu item.

It is something like this:-

|Menu1    |Menu2  |Menu3   |Menu4    |Menu5

What I want is that it doesn't come up with Menu1

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just give all the items except the first some class and use that to select them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) selector:

```css
.nav a:before {
    content: "| ";
    color: #00aeef;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.nav li:first-child a:before {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but it made all of them go away.

Comment: @Steve - Are your `a`s nested under `li`s? I should have assumed so. I updated my answer.